# Remove UL background under active LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say, we have a fixed width and fixed height DIV with background picture. Over this div or inside it there is a horisontal menu formed from unnumbered list with background color set.

Like, for example, this:

```
<div style="background-image: url("some_picture.png");>
    <ul style="background-color: some_color;">
        <li style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px;">Menu element 1</li>
        <li style="border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px;">Menu element 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There is no CSS for transforming list to horisontal menu attached, but I've added Padding and Border-Radius styles to show there is extra space over menu element names inside LIs.

Is is possible somehow to remove UL's background just under active LI? To make it transparent only under selected LI. Respecting border-radius prefarably.

No matter if it will be done through pure CSS or jQuery.

Thanks for your attention.

Help, please...

Comment: This isn't possible. The background transparency setting of a child will not affect the parent in any way.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/afa3b2c2/)?

Comment: @Imgonzalves, no, there's a background image beneath the colour, so no flat colour can be used to give the illusion

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xgdL22mt/ ???

Comment: Exactly, there is a picture beneath the UL, not a colour. It shouldn't be solved exactly like I've described, I'm not a coder at all. :) But may be there is some workaround. For those who likes tricky riddles. :)

Comment: @A.Wolff - more like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xgdL22mt/6/) (added `tabindex` and `:focus`)

Comment: @ToniLeigh ya, i missed the `selected` LI part in question

Comment: I was going to make a `clip-path` answer, but not sure I need to now

Comment: A. Wolff, still don't know, but it should at least look like this. If your solution doesn't substitute parts of pictures instead of background colour then it is exactly what I have asked for. Because my DIV's background should be a kind of slideshow. Went to check it out... :)

Comment: @Garfield - you could change the positioning values so that the LIs sat within a larger image

Comment: @Garfield - you could do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/afa3b2c2/2/). This is slightly modified though and achieved with setting a solid color to `li` instead of `ul`

Comment: @Safeer Hussain, I'm afraid UL should be covered with color as my example ment to be a horisontal menu put to a part of a DIV with background picture/slideshow. Is there a way to place a dummy LI element that will cover all empty space of a fixed width UL?

Comment: @Toni Leigh, what about a `clip-path` answer? :)

Comment: @Garfield late here, I'll have a look tomorrow, as it's a complex thing, ping me if nothing has appeared by Tuesday :-) unless someone else wants to do it ... for the record, I think the answers suggested so far in the JSFiddles are better because they use css that is much better supported and they achieve the exact effect

Comment: ping... ping... ping...

Comment: I have really tried do it myself but with no result, as expected. :) All offered suggestions (big thanks!!!) are good enough except none of them takes into account that background picture must belong to separate div. It could be whatever, even a video if css ever allows that thing (or does it already?). Please? I have broken my mind already.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you said, the div has a fixed height, for example `div {height:200px; width: 100px;}`

You could remove the background from your `ul` element and assign it to each `li` element, changing the background position:

Lets guess an `li`s height is `50px`

```
li {
 background-image: url(example.jpg);
 background-size: 200px 100px;
}
li:hover {background: none;}
li:nth-child(1) {background-position: 0 0;}
li:nth-child(2) {background-position: 0 50px;}
li:nth-child(3) {background-position: 100px;}
li:nth-child(4) {background-position: 0 150px;}
```

This is pure css, you could use jQuery to create a variable menu!

Comment: I actually like this better than the fiddle, less hacky